# How can I remap left-backspace to escape on the Colemak keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

My keyboard setup is this command:

```
exec setxkbmap -layout us,us -variant altgr-intl,colemak -option caps:escape,grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

It maps caps lock to escape for qwerty, but in Colemak, there is a backspace key where caps lock used to be (which is why my question is not exactly the same as [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270088/mapping-capslock-to-escape-for-colemak-layout)). I want to remap Colemak's left-backspace to escape, but keep my right-backspace key the same. Is there a way to do that, preferably with an easy command, like the command above?

Comment: Look at [xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make backspace act as escape using setxkbmap?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212573/22142)

Comment: @donn_crissti disagree.  it's not a duplicate of that; he's wrong about the no-capslock-key thing; but xkb isn't applying the `caps:escape` option to the second layout, which is the root of the question.  (also ignore `xmodmap` suggestions.)

Answer (score 0):

You can see in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` that the key is still called `<CAPS>` even though it produces `BackSpace` symbols.

Look at `setxkbmap -print` -- see the `us(colemak):2` in the `xkb_symbols` line?

```
$ setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(altgr-intl)+us(colemak):2+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)+capslock(escape)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

I think a `+capslock(escape):2` added to that line should work, but doesn't seem to, and I'm not familiar enough with multiple-group layouts to know whether this is a general problem with XKB options or a syntax I'm missing.

---

You may need to provide a modified colemak definition:

```
// colemak layout with escape on capslock instead of backspace
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "colemak-esc" {
    // start with existing colemak layout
    include "us(colemak)"

    key <CAPS> { [ Escape, Escape, Escape, Escape ] }
};
```

You can add that to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`, or your own file in `$HOME/.xkb/symbols`, and load it with `setxkbmap`.  See some additional references for where and how to load:

- [XKB basics, user locations](https://askubuntu.com/a/896297/669043)
- [XKB user overrides](https://superuser.com/a/1168603/685512)
- [rules and groups](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355404/222377)